# Regular expression - no capture for negative character class

Tags: regex, sed

I am trying to write different sed scripts for beautifying ruby code.
One of the cases i am trying to solve is to replace `a=>b` or `a=> b` strings with `a => b`.
The regex for matching this condition is `[^ ]=>` but it also matches 1 character before `=>`.
So, when i try to replace it is not giving me the desired result with `s/[^ ]=>/ =>/g`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try replacing `\s*=>\s*` with `{space}=>{space}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a capture:

```
s/\([^ ]\)=>/\1 =>/g
```

Comment: That worked in Vim thanks! But the same dosent seem to be working in sed.

Comment: sed -i 's/\([^ ]\)=>/\1 =>/g' app/models/campaign.rb  
sed: 1: "app/models/campaign.rb": command a expects \ followed by text

Comment: This worked. sed -i '' 's/([^ ])=>/\1 =>/g' app/models/campaign.rb

Comment: @PratikKhadloya: I have no idea why that would work; I would have expected you to need to use the `-r` command-line flag with GNU sed in order to avoid having to use `\(` for captures. But I'm glad you got it working.

Comment: @PratikKhadloya: Yes, the `-i` flag can be used to (appear to) do edits in place. But I don't think it changes the type of regex used by `sed`. Otherwise, you'd need to use `s/\(...`, but you seem to be saying that you used `s/(...`.

Answer (score 0):

How about replacing both sides unconditionally?

```
s/ ?=> ?/ => /g
```